# Running multiple instances with multiple volumes via docker-compose

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose

I want to be able to run 3 instances of Cassandra via docker with volumes mapped on host machine.

I tried to use it via this docker-compose.yml by running *docker-compose up --scale cassandra=3* but it is not starting them correctly and showing errors as I am mapping one volume to all instances.

```
version: "2"
services:
  cassandra:
      image: cassandra

      volumes:
        - /opt/se/docker-volumes/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra
```

Is it possible to map multiple volumes for multiple instances within docker-compose.yml file?

I tried to run 3 instances without defining volumes and it is working fine.

Comment: It is unfotunately not possible, see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4579

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to that when the different instances are starting, they are writing data to the same volume. This is causing many race conditions, and is corrupting the `/var/lib/cassandra` directory for each instance.

To solve this issue, you need to map each instance to a separate volume. You can achieve that by removing the volume mapping inside the compose file, and leave it to docker to create the data volumes, since `/var/lib/cassandra` is declared as a `VOLUME` inside the Dockerfile of cassandra.

Alternatively, you can manually declare three cassandra services and map each of them to a separate volume.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you do not want to do it like this?

```
version: "2"
 services:
   cassandra1:
     image: cassandra
     volumes:
       - /volume1:/var/lib/cassandra
   cassandra2:
     image: cassandra
     volumes:
       - /volume2:/var/lib/cassandra
   cassandra3:
     image: cassandra
     volumes:
       - /volume3:/var/lib/cassandra
```

Comment: No I just wanted to see if we can have any way to map these volumes from *docker-compose.yml* dynamically for no. of instances.

This way I will have to create a new service whenever I require another addition to cluster.